# What's an easy (drag-and-drop), cross-platform way to transfer files on a LAN?

Tags: file-transfer

I need to transfer some files and folders from a Windows PC to a Mac (they are on the same LAN), with the following constraints:

- I don't want to use a shared folder as the files can be located anywhere on the disk.
- Dropbox is also not an option as I don't want to upload my files to Internet.
- I'm looking for something similar to AirDrop (drag'n'drop files and folders back and forth, etc.), except not Wifi-only, and cross-platform.

The way I'm doing it right now is through Skype (I set up two different accounts on the two machines), but it won't let me transfer folders, just files.

Should I investigate private trackers and Bittorrent?

Comment: You should be able to share folders so each machine can see the others. I know you can do it so Windows can see Linux folders, but I don't know how you'd do it for MacOS.

Comment: Thing is, I would have to share almost every folder on both machines, which is why I don't want to do this.

Comment: You need to make that clear in the question otherwise you'll get it suggested as an answer (I clearly missed it!). Also why don't you want to share the entire disk? If you set the permissions correctly then there shouldn't be a problem with unauthorised people seeing the files.

Comment: Just initiate the transfers from the source machine. Then you can use a single shared directory on the destination server using any of the available protocols and don't need to worry where the files come from.

Comment: go go thumbdrives

Comment: @kobaltz "[Go-Go-Gadget thumbdrives](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inspector_Gadget#Premise)!"

Comment: @kobaltz Hmmm... that sounds a bit tedious.

Comment: Hmmm... Guys, why the downvotes? Is this not superuser.com material?!

Comment: @julien_c - Your question is extremely broad.  What you want is not pratical, you want to be able to share any folder on either machine, that simply is not reasonable.  You can always use a network drive that can be seen by both machines, and move the content to that drive, you want to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Transfer on LAN](http://code.google.com/p/transfer-on-lan/). Then, you can transfer files and folders on a LAN. It works on Windows, Mac and Linux because it uses Java 6. It needs no configuration and it is open source. Also, you can use the drag-and-drop.

Comment: I had seen that, but was hoping to find something a little more "polished". I'll give it a try. Thanks for answering my question!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to share the entire Mac hard drive. That seems to accomplish all your goals.

Then you use net use commands to mount the drive in windows, such as:

```
net use \\OSX_IP /user:osxuser
```

I do it in a domain environment all the time. It should just prompt the Windows 7 machine for credentials, like any other smb share.